# Hiding the result of a calculation in an interactive panel until all the inputs are entered

Tags: output-formatting, interactive, user-interface

I created a partial fraction calculator using the Mathematica command Apart. The image below displays the value 1 before the numerator and/or denominator are entered. How can the code be fixed so that PF doesn't output any result until one or both entries are filled? I prefer that initially the output just displays PF= and not PF=1.

[image]

The code I used is here:

```
Panel@
DynamicModule[{num, denom},
Column[
{Row[{Spacer[160], 
  Style["Partial Fraction Calculator", FontFamily -> "Helv", 18]}],
Spacer[{0, 20}],
Row[
 {Style[
   Control[{{num, Null, Style["numerator =", 18]}, 
     ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], FontFamily -> "Helv", 24]}],
Spacer[{0, 20}],
Row[
 {Style[
   Control[{{denom, Null, Style["denominator =", 18]}, 
     ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], FontFamily -> "Helv", 24]}],
Spacer[{0, 20}],
Dynamic[
 Panel[
  pf := Apart[num/denom];
  Row[{Spacer[200], Style["PF = ", FontFamily -> "Helv", 18], 
    Style[pf, FontFamily -> "Helv", 30]}],
  Background -> White]]}]]
```

Comment: Change the `Style` of `pf` to `Style[pf, FontFamily -> "Helv", 30, 
 If[num === Null || denom === Null, White, Black]]`

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: Clever>

Comment: I have updated my answer, supplying code that is both better and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build your panel with `Grid`. Like so:

```
DynamicModule[{num, denom, pf},
  pf[n_, d_] := If[(n === Null || d === Null), "", Apart[num/denom]];
  Framed @
    Panel[
      Grid[
        {{"numerator",
          Style[Control[{{num, Null, ""}, ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], 24]},
         {"denominator", 
          Style[Control[{{denom, Null, ""}, ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], 24]},
         {Row[
            {"PF =      ",
             Dynamic @
               Panel[Style[pf[num, denom], 24], 
                 Background -> White, ImageSize -> {400, 60}]}],
          SpanFromLeft}},
        BaseStyle -> {18},
        Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}],
      Style["Partial Fraction Calculator", 18],
      Top,
      Background -> White],
   TrackedSymbols :> {num, denom}]
```

When first evaluated it will look like this:

[image: initial_panel]

After entering expressions into bot input fields, it might end up looking like this:

[image: filled_panel]

I really think `Grid` is a better choice than a `Column` containing several `Row` expressions. I also think it better to use `Panel`'s 2nd argument to make the title rather than adding another row to the grid.

#### Update

I can no longer remember what problem I encountered that made me use `Row` to format the bottom row of the grid, but it was not necessary. Indeed, dispensing with `Row` simplifies the code while improving the alignment of the items in the bottom row with those in the upper two.

```
DynamicModule[{num, denom, pf}, 
  pf[n_, d_] := If[(n === Null || d === Null), "", Apart[num/denom]];
  Framed @
    Panel[
      Grid[
        {{"numerator", 
          Style[Control[{{num, Null, ""}, ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], 24]},
         {"denominator", 
          Style[Control[{{denom, Null, ""}, ImageSize -> {400, 40}}], 24]},
         {"PF = ",
          Dynamic @
            Panel[Style[pf[num, denom], 24],
              Background -> White, ImageSize -> {400, 60}]}},
        BaseStyle -> {18},
        Alignment -> {{Right, Left}}],
      Style["Partial Fraction Calculator", 18], Top,
      Background -> White],
  TrackedSymbols :> {num, denom}]
```

[image: pane]